# Check that each element in collection is not empty

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

How to simply check that each element in collection of strings is not empty using some annotation?

```
List<String> strings;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to achieve this with Bean Validation / Hibernate Validator.

You are dealing with the same issue discussed in the Validator [HV-296](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-296) as well the Bean Validation [BVAL-202](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-202) issue tracker.

One thing you could try is to implement a

```
public class NotEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmpty, Iterable<String>>
```

You then register this custom constraint validator via *validation.xml*. However, this is more than just adding an annotation.

Hibernate Validator 5.2 will offer support for Java 8 type annotations. There you will be able to write:

```
List<@NotEmpty String> strings;
```

See also [HV-877](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-877).